# In Guidewire Test Framework (GTF) while running "npm exec gt-ui-tests -- --cucumberTags="@PolicyCreation" getting error

Tags: javascript-automation, guidewire

In Guidewire Test Framework (GTF) while running "npm exec gt-ui-tests --  --cucumberTags="@PolicyCreation" getting error "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Observation:
Able to launch the URL in browser, but if I am running the Cucumber GT: UI test I am getting the error in the terminal "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate", I have tried the below options but no luck
"allow_insecure_app_urls": "true",
"ignore-certificate-errors": "true",

Answer (score 3):

Guidewire Community article 000038472 documents how to get access to NPM packages when blocked by vpn or firewall rules.

https://community.guidewire.com/s/article/How-to-download-npm-packages-for-Guidewire-GT-UI-Framework  (login required)

Alternatively, if possible, disable your vpn to allow the packages to be downloaded.  This should only be necessary one time.

Comment: I am using Hakuba version and I have got the "node_modules" folder from GW and pasted Framework level folder. Do we need to place it in insude "ui" folder?

Comment: The article states that this workaround is good to Elysian but I don't have further information.  The instructions in the article are below:

1. unzip(OfflineLibraries.zip) the package attached to this article
2. copy the node_modules directory into gt-ui root directory (gt-framework/gt-ui)
3. replace the package-lock.json in gt-framework/gt-ui user directory
4. run following command to proceed further
npm install

Comment: Yeah you are correct, but I have done that already, the actual issue is I am getting "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate" in the terminal. 

Command: npm exec gt-ui-tests --  --cucumberTags="@General_Liability"

Feature: GL_PolicySubmission
× Scenario: New submission for General Liability

   1) Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

      Browser: Chrome 121.0.0.0 / Windows 10

1/1 failed (3s)
Warnings (1):

Comment: Sorry I don't have more information on this topic.  I do see that the product documentation does have more detailed instructions for the installation of these offline libraries.  Please review the docs at the link below (requires login).  If this doesn't help you proceed then please open a case with Guidewire support for assistance.  https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/testing/202310/install/gt-framework-installation/t_download_install_gtui_offline_libraries.html

Comment: The above issue has been resolved by adding this line in NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 in the .env file under the config folder. We need to create a .env file.
Thanks for your support.